# How to Enable Input TextBox After selecting Custom Option From Drop Down?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular5

JSON DATA

```
 loginValue: any[] = [
    { value: 'col-1', viewValue: 'facebook' },
    { value: 'col-2', viewValue: 'google' },
    { value: 'col-1', viewValue: 'Custom' }
  ];
```

HTML

```html
<mat-form-field>
                    <mat-select placeholder="login Value" [disabled]="isDisabled1">
                      <mat-option *ngFor="let loginvalue of loginValue" [value]="loginvalue.value">
                        {{loginvalue.viewValue}}
                      </mat-option>
                    </mat-select>
                  </mat-form-field>

                  <div class="col-md-2">
                  <mat-form-field class="Custom">
                    <input matInput placeholder="Enter Custom Value" [disabled]="isDisabled1">
                  </mat-form-field>
```

I have three values into my drop down option facebook/ google/ Custom When i select facebook and Google the textbox input must get disabled and when i clicked on Custom option the input text box get enabled 
how to write logic in typescript or everything could be done in HTML Only?
Thanks In Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is model binding to variable:  `[(ngModel)]="selectedValue"` and use that in disabled attribute. and then check disabled attribute like this

```
  [disabled]="selectedValue.viewValue!=='Custom'"
```

Please note : `[value]="loginvalue"`

Check examples [here](https://material.angular.io/components/select/examples) you will find ngmodel example

Here is the code that I changed.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <mat-select placeholder="login Value" [(ngModel)]="selectedValue" [disabled]="isDisabled1">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let loginvalue of loginValue" [value]="loginvalue">
            {{loginvalue.viewValue}}
        </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>

<div class="col-md-2">
    <mat-form-field class="Custom">
        <input matInput placeholder="Enter Custom Value" [disabled]="selectedValue.viewValue!=='Custom'">
                  </mat-form-field>
  </div>
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mat-select-data-tre8cp?file=app%2Fselect-form-example.html)

Comment: @ShreeBatale sorry I didn't save stackblitz properly, its now even more simpler with the new changes, please checkout

Comment: ERROR Error: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup
       directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

Comment: @can you edit stackblitz and show me where is the problem?

Comment: i guess you need to initialize fromControlName in constructor

Answer (score 3):

You could try using Reactive Forms by subscribing on your selected option and manipulate enabling/disabling your input control.

**TS:**

```
changeState() {
    this.form.get('logintype').valueChanges
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (res === "Custom") { this.form.get('customInput').enable() }
        else { this.form.get('customInput').disable() }
      });
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <mat-form-field>
        <mat-select formControlName="logintype" placeholder="Select an option" (selectionChange)="changeState()">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let option of loginValue" [value]="option.viewValue">
                {{ option.viewValue }}
            </mat-option>
        </mat-select>
    </mat-form-field>

    <mat-form-field>
        <input matInput formControlName="customInput" type="text">
  </mat-form-field>

</form>
```

Here's a sample code on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wpztwi?file=app%2Fselect-value-binding-example.html)